# Using classes on Android Studio in Unity

Tags: javascript, java, android-studio, unity-game-engine, cross-platform

I created a project on Android Studio (Bluetooth server socket that receives a constant stream of data) and I was wondering if it was possible to turn it into a .dll that I can use on Unity? Unity uses Javascript but the code is in Java, but I understand that Java can be embedded in JavaScript if I make it a library. I did a decent amount of research and used the gradle to export a .jar file and then I read that I can use IKVM to turn a .jar into a .dll, but someone said that IKVM can't be used for android projects? Is this true? And if so, is there a way that I can use the class on Unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about creating a dll, a jar is sufficient.

The end goal is to generate your_plugin.jar file, and move it to `Assets/Plugins/Android/your_plugin.jar`. Then you can access it using C# (or maybe Javascript) via the JNI.

I suggest following [this](http://www.thegamecontriver.com/2015/04/android-plugin-unity-android-studio.html) tutorial.

The jist is, in your jar file, you extend the default UnityPlayerActivity and create whatever methods you need. I'd start with something simple that just returns a string. Generate the jar file and put it in `Assets/Plugins/Android`. Create an AndroidManifest.xml in the same directory, that causes Unity to launch with your extended Activity instead of the default. On the Unity end, get a reference to the current instance of the activity you extended, and call your method, like so:

```
  // get a reference to the class
  AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");

  // get a reference to the class instance from a static variable
  AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("currentActivity");

  // call a method in your UnityPlayer class that returns a string
  String s = currentActivity.Call<string>("myJavaMethodReturningString");
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides JavaScript Unity 3d also supportrs C# 
Take a look here maybe it helps...

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/330809/integration-of-jar-file-using-jni.html